# How does one do negative queries against nested objects in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index whose documents contain a list of nested objects. A simplified version of the mappings is as follows:

```
{
  "_doc": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
      "things": {
        "type": "nested",
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "version": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get all documents that *do not* have *any* nested thing-objects with a specific set of values. Queries like

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "things",
      "query": {
        "bool": { 
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "name": "thing1"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "version": "1.0.0"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

appear to just return all documents that have *some* nested document that doesn't match... which means it still returns all documents, even those that *also do* have a nested object which matches. So, how do I properly filter those out?

EDIT: Queries like

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "things",
            "query": {
              "bool": { 
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "name": "thing1"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "version": "1.0.0"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

which nest the nested object query inside a `must_not` also do not work, and still just return everything.

Comment: As far as I know: Your nested query will apply to what is found, but for that nested type.

What you probably want is a wrapper function to make your query nested query itself a `must`, but your actual query: `query: { bool: { must_not: [ nestedQuery - that does find things ] } }`

It's not ideal, but a workaround I found

Comment: @Tessmore Sadly, that doesn't appear to work, either. :(

Comment: Oki, I might not understand completely: If you don't want `thing1` as a name OR `version = 1.0.0` then the nested thingy can be a `should` and now that I read it again, I think that is what you mean?  So the bool query inside the nested query can be `should`.  If your use-case is different, maybe show an example document that matches and one that should not (but is now being returned)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I eventually figured it out myself. It turns out that, despite explicitly specifying the `path` field in a nested object query already, the names of fields of nested objects still have to be fully qualified. Thus, this works:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "things",
      "query": {
        "bool": { 
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "things.name": "thing1"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "things.version": "1.0.0"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```